# .NET MVC 4 Form of Forms to pass in a FormCollection of FormCollections?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, formcollection

I'm new to .Net MVC 4 with Razor, and it's totally possible I'm approaching this the wrong way, but here's my issue: I'm trying to build a site that displays records in a grid, which each record allowing for edits, and a submit all button at the end. Within each record the user can add a comment and click on a save button (on the row they're editing), which posts back to the controller with the FormCollection for the corresponding row. The problem is the submit all button at the end. The user should be able to make edits to many rows and click the submit all button to save changes to all records without clicking each row's save button separately.

I've been trying to use a Form of Forms approach to this, by encapsulating the entire table in a form which will post back to an action method which will cycle through the FormCollections in the FormCollection parameter to call the Save function for each one that has been changed. It seems like Razor doesn't like the whole Form of Forms idea. Is there a better way to add this functionality?

Here's my View:

```
    @using COM.COMPANY.APPS.MODELS
    @model COM.COMPANY.APPS.WEBAPP.ViewModels.MyModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Web Application Title";
    }

    @using(Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home"))
    {

        <h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
        @Html.CheckBox("CheckAll", false) //Flags All Projects For Approval
        <div>
            <table id="projGrid">
                <tr>
                    <th>Check to Approve</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    <th>Save</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.List)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @using(Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home"))
                        { 
                            <td class='narrowCell'>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.isApproved)
                            </td> 
                            <td class='textInputCell'>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => item.NewComment, 6, 40, new { title = "New Comments...", @class = "defaultText" })</td>
                            <td class='narrowCell'><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td> 
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

And here's my Controller Save function:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
    {
        bool isAppr = Convert.ToBoolean(form["item.isApproved"].ToString().Contains("true"));
        string newComment = form["item.NewComment"];

        try
        {
            DataItem item = new DataItem
            {
                isApproved = isAppr,
                NewComment = newComment
            };

            DataGateway.SaveDataItem(item);
            return Index();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAILED TO SAVE RECORD");
            return Index();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection form)
    {
        //Need to collect form of forms here
        return Index();
    }
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. I was thinking of just using one large form over the whole table and having the individual Save buttons use a javascript function to pass in a record id parameter - that way if the parameter is set the save function saves only that record's fields from the FormCollection, and if not then it runs through and saves all.

Comment: Nested forms are not valid in HTML.

Comment: Why pass a form collection to your controller when you already have a model ?

Comment: The model contains recordsets from several different tables, so I've set it up this way to produce the rows reflecting each record from one of those sets of data in the model. Is there some view enhancement I can use to bind the input values to the model better, like so that the data in the model is updated as soon as they change any of the input elements?

Comment: Or can I pass the model itself back to the controller?

Comment: @Sujikahalwa ViewModel was created to solve this problem, just create one that fits exatcly what you have to receive from the form. Don't use FormCollection!!! The ModelBinder will do the hardwork. Expect as parameter the Model or ViewModel.

Comment: @Fals Okay I've switched to using a ViewModel - thank you!